# Sharepoint Online site will not display comments box on homepage

Tags: comments, sharepoint-online

I have a Sharepoint Online site - one of many - but this one will not display the "comments" box at the bottom of the home page, when enabled and published. Other site pages have this no problem.
I click the slider to "ON" and then "Republish", but the comments box does not appear.

One the same homepage, incidentally, I am NOT seeing the "Likes /Views /Save for Later" options either. But I do see these on the other pages of the site, so this might be related?

Anyone got any ideas? There is no custom code or scripting, and Comments are obviously enabled at a tenancy level.

Answer (score -1):

Well "it fixed itself" but it took over 2 days to do it!